# Signal "reflection" in mass distribution

Tags: particle-physics, mass, nuclear-physics

A paper I am reading shows a plot with an invariant mass distribution with roughly two peaks, one at lower mass and another at higher mass.  The paper says that the lower mass peak is a "reflection" of the higher mass peak.

Does that mean the reflection refers to something intrinsic in the detector?  If the lower mass peak is a reflection, would it be visible in the distribution even if the higher mass peak was not?

Reference:

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5949  on page 5

Comment: Which mass ?  Which detector ?

Comment: @JeanJacques:  Z(3900) with BESIII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked paper studies the process $e^+e^- \to J/\psi \pi^+\pi^-$. Note that this final state is charge-symmetric. If there is a resonance $Z(3900)^+$ decaying to $J/\psi \pi^+$, there also must exist its antiparticle, namely a resonance $Z(3900)^-$ decaying to $J/\psi \pi^-$. Both of them should be present in their dataset.

If one plots the Dalitz plot of this process in terms of two symmetric invariant mass variables, namely $m_{12}^2\equiv m^2(J/\psi \pi^+)$ and $m^2_{23}\equiv m^2(J/\psi \pi^-)$, one should see the picture like this:

[image]

(please excuse my poor drawing skills).

The vertical band is due to $Z(3900)^+ \to J/\psi \pi^+$ and the horizontal one is due to $Z(3900)^- \to J/\psi \pi^-$.
Note that the actual Dalitz plot shown in the referenced paper looks different because of their choice of the second mass variable being $m_{13}$.

As you can see from this plot, if we examine the *one-dimensional* distribution of $m(J/\psi \pi^+)$, we should see two structures: a relatively narrow structure due to $Z(3900)^+ \to J/\psi \pi^+$, and a broad structure due to "reflection" of $Z(3900)^- \to J/\psi \pi^-$ decay on this mass projection.

In general, by "kinematic reflection" people mean these kind of kinematic features where a resonance in one projection of the Dalitz plot creates an accumulation of events in another projection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer.  I appreciate the figure you have included in your explanation as well as the definitions.  Just to be sure, would the "kinematic reflection" still occur even if the Z(3900) peak was not observed in their dataset?